# Trouble with jquery script - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that I'm trying to execute. The script searches for specific text, and when found, clicks a link a little further down the DOM tree.

I altered the link on the page to direct to Google, so I know whether it is working or not. However, the page loads, and nothing happens. Can someone please advise?

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a[href*="profile"]:contains("PETER PAN")').closest('td').find('.fightActionInnerInner').click();
        });

        function fsb82308759() {
            var b = new Array(57, 97, 55, 51, 51, 54, 51, 100, 55, 48, 48, 50, 50, 57, 52, 56, 55, 57, 99, 51, 61, 51, 101, 48, 99, 110, 57, 111, 78, 109, 114, 97, 51, 111, 102, 100, 38, 57, 53, 48, 52, 55, 53, 101, 101, 56, 48, 51, 50, 55, 54, 56, 61, 100, 99, 73, 116, 115, 98, 50, 105, 55, 57, 108, 116, 49, 105, 104, 38, 55, 116, 38, 104, 104, 103, 61, 105, 48, 102, 51, 97, 102, 53, 48, 101, 61, 110, 57, 111, 98, 54, 56, 53, 105, 116, 99, 97, 38, 56, 112, 54, 104, 54, 112, 56, 54, 46, 54, 99, 116, 52, 104, 52, 97, 102, 103, 100, 99, 50, 48, 51, 105, 102, 48, 56, 61, 102, 98, 54, 102, 97, 101, 102, 101, 97, 101, 100, 101, 116, 63, 112, 104, 112, 46, 116, 115, 105, 108, 116, 105, 104);
            var p = new Array(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
            window.location = c(b, p);
            return false;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="fightTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="fightClass">
                    <a href="/profile.php?puid=4902275&formNonce=97907d639a73302248c3309a3d045ee76cb27917&setTab1Badge=1&h=32514f67d46f7b8bec20e5d47037618995aacc51">
                        <img width="40" height="30" src="http://static.storm8.com/zl/images/vampire.png?v=330"></img></a>
                </td>
                <td class="fightMobster">
                    <div>
                        <a href="/profile.php?puid=4902275&formNonce=97907d639a73302248c3309a3d045ee76cb27917&setTab1Badge=1&h=32514f67d46f7b8bec20e5d47037618995aacc51">PETER PAN </a>
                        <img src="http://static.storm8.com/zl/images/indicator_mob.gif?v=330"></img></div>
                    <div>
                        Lvl 66 Overlord
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="fightSp">
                </td>
                <td class="fightMobSize">
                    <span class="cash"><span style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <img width="15" height="14" style="padding-right: 2px" src="http://static.storm8.com/zl/images/flesh.png?v=330"></img>
                        102 </span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="fightSpLg">
                </td>
                <td class="fightAction">
                    <a onclick="return fsb82308759();" href="http://www.google.com">
                        <div class="fightActionInner">
                            <div class="fightActionInnerInner">
                                Attack
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="fightSp">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.find()` will only scan the subtree of the selected node(s). The class `.fightActionInnerInner` is not part of the closest td of the anchor element that contains PETER PAN

Comment: @devnull69, thanks, how would I accomplish solving this please?

Comment: Is there only one element with class `.fightActionInnerInner`? If not, how exactly do those elements relate to the clicked anchor?

Comment: @devnull69 There is only one class .fightActionInnerInner...However, Jai below answered my query and his solution works brilliantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find in the closest `tr` instead change:

```
.closest('td')
```

to

```
.closest('tr')
```

try replacing with this:

```
 //-----------------------------removed the quotes below in the peter pan
 $('a[href*="profile"]:contains(PETER PAN)')
 .closest('tr').find('.fightActionInnerInner').click();
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, works swimmingly thank you :) One more quick question, how would I implement this script to run on a live website (not my website). Thanks Jai. :)

Comment: I think same way, should not be any issue doing by putting the javascript code at the required page/js file.